# Monodroid C# 2D Game Engine for my game?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have written a text-based simulation game in C# using Xamarin Studio/Monodroid, but now I have the big question what Engine I should/could use to visualize my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use **[Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/)**. It allows C# code (compiled with Xamarin's Mono, as far as I know), it runs on all major platforms (Android, iOS, web browsers with a plugin) and should be relatively easy to use with its own developer toolset. Quick Google check confirms there are already frameworks for 2D games - **[this article](http://www.rocket5studios.com/tutorials/make-a-2d-game-in-unity3d-using-only-free-tools-part-1/)** shows some possibilities. I personally have yet to try it myself, but so far it looks well documented, with decent community, and some of the projects look really awesome (like SG: Deadzone, 3rd person shooter for iPhone) so I wouldn't worry about performance or anything like that.